# Correct radio syntax (not checkbox)

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, radio-button

I have this syntax to provde a series of checkboxes. This works fine, however no matter what syntax I use to get radios I get nothing, just a blank space.

I've tried `'type' => 'radio'`, and tried `'type' => 'radiogroup'`.

This what I'm using now:

```
array(
'type' => 'checkbox',
"holder" => "div",
"class" => "",
"heading" => __("Choose your cheese topping", 'rbm_menu_item'),
'param_name' => 'cheesbox',
'value' => array( 'Cheddar'=>'Chedder', 'Gouda'=>' Gouda', 'Bleu'=>' Bleu'),
"description" => __("<br /><hr class='gduo'>", 'rbm_menu_item')
),
```

Any ideas? Is there a different way to get radios instead of checkboxes?

Comment: what framework are you using ?

Comment: @Sylwit: Having done some digging, this looks like Visual Composer for WordPress.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using visual composer (WPBakery Page Builder) try this:

```
vc_add_shortcode_param( 'simple_radio', 'xyz_function' );
function xyz_function($param, $value){
if(!empty($value)){
    $hval = $value;
}
else{
    $hval = '';
}
$ret = '<input type="hidden" value="'.$hval.'" id="xyz'.$param['param_name'].'" name="'.$param['param_name'].'" class="wpb_vc_param_value wpb-input">';
foreach($param['value'] as $key => $p){
    if($value==$p){
        $checked = ' checked="checked"';
    }
    else{
        $checked = '';
    }
    $ret.='<div><input type="radio" name="xyz'.$param['param_name'].'" id="'.$param['param_name'].$p.'" value="'.$p.'" class="xyz-vc-radio'.$param['param_name'].'" style="width:auto; margin-right:5px;"'.$checked.'> <label for="'.$param['param_name'].$p.'">'.$key.'</label></div>';
}
$ret.='<script>
jQuery(".xyz-vc-radio'.$param['param_name'].'").change(function(){
    var s = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery("#xyz'.$param['param_name'].'").val(s);
});
</script>';
return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this code, having done some Googling and searching through documentation, is from Visual Composer for WordPress.

It looks like this is an array to be passed to `vc_map()`'s `params` key to add your shortcode to the Visual Composer content elements list.

Looking through [the `vc_map` documentation](https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=524332), it looks as if no form of radio buttons exist within Visual Composer, unfortunately.

You could [create your own param type](https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/display/VC/Create+New+Param+Type) but this seems beyond the scope of this answer. Do feel free to comment if you'd like me to go into more detail or ask another question. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes this is for VC, however after reading through the docs I get the feeling that this is (as you said) not there - dang!

Comment: @idaryl: As I say, I could see a way around it, but it seems overly complex.

Comment: Overly complex? in what way - Ive been at my wits end getting this tio work in any reasonable manner

Comment: @idaryl: I'm not sure how familiar you are with PHP, nor am I overly familiar with VC, but you'd have to essentially define a function to output radio buttons for the options under `params` and hook it up to VC using `vc_add_shortcode_param()`.